# Javascript, form validation, getting NaN

Tags: javascript

in a form, onkeypress, I call this function:

```
function calculate() {

    var subtotal = parseInt(document.form1.product1.value) * product1 + 
                    parseInt(document.form1.product2.value) * product2 + 
                    parseInt(document.form1.product3.value) * product3;
    alert(typeof subtotal);
    alert(subtotal);
    var total = subtotal + parseInt(document.form1.shipping.value);

    document.form1.subtotal.value = subtotal;
    document.form1.total.value = total;
}
```

When I alert the typeof subtotal, I get number.  But then when I alert the subtotal, I get NaN.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: Where do `productn` come from?

Comment: isFinite() function is really useful for detecting if a variable is valid number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I `alert()` the `typeof subtotal`, I get `number`.

`typeof NaN` is `number` in JavaScript.

> But then when I alert the subtotal, I get `NaN`.

`NaN` is *toxic*, if it is part of any arithmetic, the result is `NaN`.

The most probable reason is that `parseInt()` is returning `NaN`. Are those elements' `value` property an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

parseInt(null) or parseInt('') is NaN, you should be sure  than document.form1.product1.value, document.form1.product2.value or document.form1.product3.value is not null or empty, and is a number.